# Using gerund verb instead of wh-clause

Tags: gerunds

Someone can help me clearly How to use V-ing instead of WH-clauses? And when should we use it.

For example:

> I talked to him about the bug I got when I run app.

Could I convert to:

> I talked to him about the bug I got when running app.

Thanks you guys.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Give us a WH-clause that you'd like to change.

Comment: @Jim: I updated my question already.

Comment: But you still need that subordinating conjunction. All you can omit are the subject and the to be verb.

Comment: Separate issue, but I would suggest including "the" before "app" in both sentences.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know whether (and, if so, when) a participial phrase can be substituted for a relative clause -- especially a relative clause introduced by a subordinating conjunctive adverb.

First, let me address a flaw that exists in your original model:

> I talked to him about the bug I *got* when I *run* {some given app}.

This model includes a shift in tense that the average native speaker would likely reject.   I can easily understand "the bug that I *got* when I *ran* {this app}".   I can also easily understand "the bug that I *get* when I *run* {this app}".   The actions of "to get" and "to run" should exist in the same timeframe.   Either both happened at the same time in the past, or both generally happen at the same time in the ever-present and habitual present.

Putting that aside, the so-called present participle "running" can be and often is substituted in exactly this circumstance.   Your instincts have *not* led you astray.   There exist legitimate analytic frameworks in which much the same process has a name: *whiz reduction*:

> I talked to him about the bug [that / ∅] I got [while / when / ***∅***] running {this app}.

-- is a sensible reduction of --

> I talked to him about the bug [that / ∅] I got [while / when] I was running {this app}.

One advantage of using the participial phrase is that concordance in tense no longer matters.   Participles and their phrases have no tense.   The difference between "I got" and "I get" is important to its own clause, but that has no bearing on the participial phrase.   Both "[that] I get [] running {it}" and "[that] I got [] running {it}" work.

If anything, your conversion is better than the original.

As to when to use it:   Use it whenever tense shouldn't matter.   In traditional English grammar, the participles are badly named.   The present participle has nothing to do with the present, and the past participle has nothing to do with the past.   Things would make much more sense if these forms were called "the continuous participle" and "the resultative participle".   Alas, history is against us.

### tl;dr

Yes.   That conversion is very good.